# How can I merge two Delphi projects?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to merge two Delphi projects into one?

In one project I have 3 different forms with different stuff on them, but I would like to add a program I have coded a while ago into a new form in my program.

Answer (score 7):

In the Project Manager, right-click your application, and select "Add". Select then the unit (*.pas) file of the form (e.g. `Unit1.pas`). The corresponding form (e.g. `Form1.dfm`) will be added with the unit.

Comment: @noobdelphi: When the form has been added to the project. And assuming the original form is in another folder, do a save as of the form into the folder of the new project (I am assuming here that you keep all forms of one project into the same folder).